# Bat to sort files by nth character or word into folders named "n"?

Tags: batch-file, file-organization

I'm trying to make a .bat to sort a large amount of files labeled "(date) (client) - (document Title).pdf" eg "12-21-11 Thompson - Case Management.pdf" into folders titled by client.  So far I've gotten:

```
for /f "tokens=2* delims= " %%b in ('dir /b *.pdf') do (
    md %%b
```

so that %%b is the client name eg "Thompson" and its respective folder is made, but I'm not sure what to do with `move` to make it only consider %%b. The titles after "-" aren't consistent for each file, so something like `move "%%a %%b %%c %%d"` doesn't always work. Is there any way to do this?

Or, if it's easier, is there a way to only consider the 10th character when sorting files?  So "12-21-11 Thompson - Case Management" could be sorted into a folder named "T"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested:

```
 for /f "tokens=2* delims= " %%b in ('dir /b *.pdf') do (
        md %%b > nul 2>&1
        for /f %%F in ('dir /b /a:-d *%%b*.pdf') do (
           move %%F %%b
        )

    )
```

Comment: It still produces the same result, i.e. the correct folders are made but none of the files are moved. I can't seem to figure this one out...

Comment: what this prints if you use echo instead of move?

Comment: `File not found
The system cannot find the file specified
File not found`

and it only creates 1 folder called "%b", but doesn't move anything.

I did manage to figure it out though, at least in terms of using spaces as delimiters:

`for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%b in ('dir /b *.pdf ^| find "_*.pdf"') do (
 md %%b > nul 2>&1
 move *%%b*.pdf %%b
 )`

Seems to work, except in the case that the client name is something like "Hughes, B" so I've been sorting those manually.

Comment: Is there a way to parse the client name starting from the 10th character, ending at the following hyphen, then removing the trailing space just before the hyphen?

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple FOR loop to list the files, and an inner FOR /F loop to parse out the client name.

```
for %%F in (*.pdf) do for /f "tokens=2" %%A in ("%%F") do (
  if not exist "%%A\" md "%%A"
  move "%%F" "%%A"
)
```